# multi_query in php

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a database 'test' with two tables.

Here is phpmyadmin dump:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tags`
--

INSERT INTO `tags` (`name`, `id`) VALUES
('tag_one', 1),
('tag_two', 1),
('tag_three', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tags_used`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags_used` (
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `used` int(4) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tags_used`
--

INSERT INTO `tags_used` (`name`, `used`) VALUES
('tag_one', 10),
('tag_three', 10),
('tag_two', 10);
```

And here is php code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'pass', 'test');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo 'Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
else {
    $query = <<<SQL
DELETE FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'tag_one' AND `tags`.`id` = '1';
UPDATE `tags_used` SET `used` = used-1 WHERE `tags_used`.`name` = 'tag_one';
DELETE FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'tag_two' AND `tags`.`id` = '1';
UPDATE `tags_used` SET `used` = used-1 WHERE `tags_used`.`name` = 'tag_two';
DELETE FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'tag_three' AND `tags`.`id` = '1';
UPDATE `tags_used` SET `used` = used-1 WHERE `tags_used`.`name` = 'tag_three';
SQL;

    $query = trim($query);
    $mysqli->multi_query($query);
    $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

After execution 'tag_three' is still in the `tags` table.
And when I run this SQL through phpmyadmin it works fine.
Where am I wrong?

---

mysql 5.1.42
php 5.3.1
windows 2003
nginx 0.8.32

---

MySQL.log

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld, Version: 5.1.42-community-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
TCP Port: 3306, Named Pipe: (null)
Time                 Id Command    Argument
100821 12:25:52     1 Connect   root@localhost on test
            1 Query DELETE FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'tag_one' AND `tags`.`id` = '1';
UPDATE `tags_used` SET `used` = used-1 WHERE `tags_used`.`name` = 'tag_one';
DELETE FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'tag_two' AND `tags`.`id` = '1';
UPDATE `tags_used` SET `used` = used-1 WHERE `tags_used`.`name` = 'tag_two';
DELETE FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'tag_three' AND `tags`.`id` = '1';
UPDATE `tags_used` SET `used` = used-1 WHERE `tags_used`.`name` = 'tag_three'
100821 12:27:37     2 Connect   root@localhost on 
            2 Query SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
            2 Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'
            2 Query SHOW PLUGINS
            2 Init DB   test
            2 Init DB   test
            2 Query SELECT * FROM `tags`
 LIMIT 0, 30
            2 Query SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `test` LIKE 'tags%'
            2 Query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test`.`tags`
            2 Init DB   test
            2 Init DB   test
            2 Query SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'profiling'
            2 Query SHOW FULL COLUMNS
        FROM `test`.`tags`
            2 Quit
```

*1 Connect* - It is my code
*2 Connect* - It is 'Refresh' from phpmyadmin

---

There is no errors in php logs.

---

It is stand along code. As is. There is no any queries before or after this code.

Comment: The SQL is fine so there must be something in multi_query, which I am not versed in, or you have some other query that might be adding it that tag back to the db.

Comment: Seems like http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php might have some quirks... check out the comments. Also, check out that "max_allowed_packet" thing

Comment: It works correctly for me: Ubuntu 10.04; MySQL 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.6; PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2; Apache/2.2.14

Comment: Is there any advantage in packaging those six queries into one string instead of sending six queries one by one?

Comment: It is stand along code. As is. There is no any queries before or after this code.

Comment: I checked this on: CentOS; MySQL 5.0.91-50-log; PHP 5.2.12. And it works correctly. The problem is in php multi_query function under windows I guess.

Comment: One more test on: Linux Debian 2.6.26-2-amd64; PHP 5.3.3; mysql 5.5.4; nginx/0.8.49. And as a result... 'tag_two' is still in the tags table!

Answer (score 0):

you should check your error log and maybe post a part of it here? Because it seems a quirk of the multi-query function. I've tried your code with a mostly same configuration (except for the os, win server 2008) and it worked. I've also tried modifying it into six different query, and it also worked.

I've tried changing the query into the following:

```
  $query = <<<SQL
DELETE FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'tag_one' AND `tags`.`id` = '1';
COMMIT;
UPDATE `tags_used` SET `used` = used-1 WHERE `tags_used`.`name` = 'tag_one';
COMMIT;
DELETE FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'tag_two' AND `tags`.`id` = '1';
COMMIT;
UPDATE `tags_used` SET `used` = used-1 WHERE `tags_used`.`name` = 'tag_two';
COMMIT;
DELETE FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`name` = 'tag_three' AND `tags`.`id` = '1';
COMMIT;
UPDATE `tags_used` SET `used` = used-1 WHERE `tags_used`.`name` = 'tag_three';
COMMIT;
SQL;
```

hope it works for you

Comment: I added mysql log. And php log is clear. Look there is no semicolumn (;) in the end of my query and there is no 'Quit' command too. It doesn't looks good.

Comment: I'm at lost... since it's InnoDB, you might try changing the query into the one I've edited above.. it worked for me